# Prove $r-n \le \lfloor \frac{mr}{m+n} \rfloor,$ or find all exceptions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Let $m,n,r$ be positive integers with $r\le m+n$. I want to prove

$$r-n \le \left\lfloor \frac{mr}{m+n} \right\rfloor,$$

where the notation on the right means floor. I found this inequality quite hard to prove since we can't reduce m and m+n. It is also hard to find integers exceptional to this inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left\lfloor \frac{mr}{m+n} \right\rfloor =\left\lfloor r-\frac{nr}{m+n} \right\rfloor \ge \left\lfloor r-\frac{n(n+m)}{m+n} \right\rfloor=r-n$$